# POST Request with body containing Array of IFormFile | C# / Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, rest, file

I'm trying to send from Angular client app a form that has 2 arrays, one with some basic object,
and another with files. Accepting single IFormFile by endpoint works perfectly fine, but when trying to send this I'm facing an error which is as follows:

> [ERROR] NotSupportedException - Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'. Path: $.files[0].file | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 350

Error is being thrown by C# app.

This are models:

```
public record CreateLessonPlanCommand(
    string PlanTitle,
    string PlanContent,
    LessonStageModel[] Stages,
    EducationFileModel[] Files
) : ICommand<Unit>;
```

```
public class LessonStageModel
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string StageSource { get; set; }
    public string StageContent { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class EducationFileModel
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Angular Reactive Form:

```
this.lessonPlanForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            planTitle: ['', [Validators.required]],
            planContent: ['', [Validators.required]],
            stages: this.formBuilder.array([], []),
            files: this.formBuilder.array([], [])
        });
```

And functions to handle the dynamic creation of Files formGroups:

```
files(): FormArray {
        return this.lessonPlanForm.get('files') as FormArray;
    }

    newFile(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            file: ['', [Validators.required]]
        });
    }

    addFile() {
        this.files().push(this.newFile());
    }

    removeFile(fileIndex: number) {
        this.files().removeAt(fileIndex);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? What steps should I take to resolve this error and make it work?

**EDIT:**

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost("plan")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateLessonPlan([FromBody] CreateLessonPlanCommand command)
{
    var result = await Sender.Send(command);
        
    return HandleResult(result);
}
```

FromBody was changed to FromForm and error remained in place.
What is the proper way of sending multiple files with a reactive form
from Angular to C#?

Comment: Can you provide source code for controller/action?

Comment: Question edited with endpoint code